# Evaluating expression trees in C++ using inordertraversal

Tags: c++, expression, binary-tree

This problem is given in daily coding problem #50. Suppose an arithmetic expression is given as a binary tree. Each leaf is an integer and each internal node is one of '+', '−', '∗', or '/'.

Given the root to such a tree, write a function to evaluate it.

For example, given the following tree :

```
      *
    /   \
   +     +
  / \   /  \
 3  2  4   5
```

You should return 45, as it is (3 + 2) * (4 + 5).

I first thought okay, well why don't I get a vector for the inordertraversal representation of this tree and go from there. I got a bit stuck and glanced at a solution online. I was able to understand it and reproduce it but I am not satisfied with that.

What I have so far is a inordertraversal representation of this tree in a vector: [3, +, 2, *, 4, +, 5].

I want to evaluate this from here but I am a bit stuck on the logic.

Here is the code I have thus far that does not work. Note that `binary_tree_calculate2` is the function I am trying to work on.

```
// Daily coding problem #50
// This problem was asked by Microsoft.
// Suppose an arithmetic expression is given as a binary tree. Each leaf is an integer and each internal node is one of
// '+', '−', '∗', or '/'.
// Given the root to such a tree, write a function to evaluate it.
// For example, given the following tree :
//     *
//   /   \
//  +     +
// / \   /  \
// 3  2  4   5
// You should return 45, as it is (3 + 2) * (4 + 5).

#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct TreeNode
{
    std::string val;
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> left = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> right = nullptr;

    TreeNode(std::string x, std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> &&p = nullptr, std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> &&q = nullptr) :
        val(x),
        left(std::move(p)),
        right(std::move(q)){}
};


int get_num(std::string c)
{
    return std::stoi(c);
}

auto inordertraversal(std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>& root)
{
    std::vector<std::string> res;
    if (!root)
        return res;

    auto left = inordertraversal(root->left);
    auto right = inordertraversal(root->right);
    res.insert(res.end(), left.begin(), left.end());
    res.push_back(root->val);
    res.insert(res.end(), right.begin(), right.end());
}

int binary_tree_calculate1(std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>& root)
{

    if (!root)
        return 0;

    if (!root->left && !root->right)
        return get_num(root->val);

    int l = binary_tree_calculate1(root->left);
    int r = binary_tree_calculate1(root->right);

    if (root->val == "+")
        return l + r;

    if (root->val == "-")
        return l - r;

    if (root->val == "*")
        return l * r;

    return l/r;
}

int binary_tree_calculate2(std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>& root)
{
    auto tree_node = inordertraversal(root);
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tree_node.size(); ++i)
    {
        int num = get_num(tree_node[i]);
        if (tree_node[i] == "+")
            result += num;
        if (tree_node[i] == "-")
            result -= num;
        if (tree_node[i] == "*")
            result *= num;
        result /= num;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> root = std::make_unique<TreeNode>("*");
    root->left = std::make_unique<TreeNode>("+");
    root->left->left = std::make_unique<TreeNode>("3");
    root->left->right = std::make_unique<TreeNode>("2");
    root->right = std::make_unique<TreeNode>("+");
    root->right->right = std::make_unique<TreeNode>("5");
    root->right->left = std::make_unique<TreeNode>("4");

    std::cout << binary_tree_calculate1(root) << "\n";
    std::cout << binary_tree_calculate2(root) << "\n";


    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `if (tree_node[i] == "*")  result *= num; result /= num;` -- Are you debugging your code, or just writing code and hope that it works?  Do you see something wrong with that piece of code, like what is the last statement doing there?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Tbh I maybe just writing code with the hopes that it works, but I am trying to sort of follow the same idea with what the first solution does and incorporate it into the idea I had.

Comment: not sure what is wrong with `binary_tree_calculate1` it's how i would have written it

Comment: @Wolfy A very simple debugging session would have shown you that glaring mistake.

Comment: @sp2danny There isn't anything wrong with that solution but I was only able to produce that code after seeing a similar solution online so doesn't feel like my own.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am still learning how to debug effectively could you suggest where I should add some break points?

Comment: You could have printed out `result` -- or better yet, learn to use the debugging tools that come with the compiler you're using.  If it's Visual Studio, you get no pass for not using the Debug menu option when it is right there on the main menu and is as simple as hitting the F10 key to start debugging.  If you're using g++, you have gdb.  If you're using an IDE that uses g++ under the hood, then the IDE should have a Debug menu option.

Comment: the most fundamental problem with the approach to make a vector, is that different trees, that should parse to different results, will end up with the same vector representation, and thus that idea cannot work, atleast not without introducing parenthesises.

Comment: @sp2danny Okay so does that mean its going to be more difficult to get it working? I find it hard to sometimes come up or finish my own solution without glancing or looking at a solution. Any advice?

Comment: @Wolfy -- How was that tree created from the original expression?  It didn't just appear out of thin air.  I bet it was done in postfix style.  How would you have created a tree from this expression `3 + 2 * 4 + 5`?  What would that tree look like?

Comment: for this particular problem, you probably just have to accept that the code does not feel like your own, since it's basically the only way that is not unworkably convoluted.

Comment: well actually, have a look at [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), it might be a way to create your "own" version

Comment: @Wolfy `auto inordertraversal(std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>& root)` -- Having a closer look, that function does not do an in-order traversal.  It is post-order (Left, Right, Node).  An inorder traversal is (Left, Node, Right).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Whoops my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious error is that in `binary_tree_calculate2`, you are taking `result` and corrupting it with a division at the end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tree_node.size(); ++i)
{
    int num = get_num(tree_node[i]);
    if (tree_node[i] == "+")
        result += num;
    if (tree_node[i] == "-")
        result -= num;
    if (tree_node[i] == "*")
        result *= num;
    result /= num;  // <-- What is this line doing?
}
```

In short, you are missing `else` statements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tree_node.size(); ++i)
{
    int num = get_num(tree_node[i]);
    if (tree_node[i] == "+")
        result += num;
    else
    if (tree_node[i] == "-")
        result -= num;
    else
    if (tree_node[i] == "*")
        result *= num;
    else 
        result /= num;
}
```

Note that the assumption is that `tree_node[i]` is going to have a mathematical operation symbol, and for division, `num` is not 0.

The difference in `binary_tree_calculate1` is that a `return` is done immediately after each calculation, thus the error doesn't exist in that function.

Comment: I see but the result still returns 0 and not 45? Is my approach just not a good idea?

Comment: I pointed out one mistake.  Whether it is the only mistake is another story.  But look at the comments in the main section.  You started out with this mysterious "tree" created from magic, and told to parse it.  You should go back to the beginning and ask your teacher or whoever gave you the picture of the tree -- how did you create that tree from that expression?

Comment: I don't have a teacher unfortunately, on my own here. I saw you mentioned postfix in the latter above I know that from a mathematics perspective but I don't really see how it would help me in terms of fixing the existing code.